# Decomplie, edit and rebuild .NET DLL

Tags: .net, dll, build, disassembly

I have .NET 6 WPF builded application with one .DLL file (named as VS Project) and .EXE file.
In short, this app get data from database. I dont have source codes, but I known, that somewhere in code there is a database connection string. I want change it (cause database server has been changes).

I tried:

- Used dotpeek for disassembly .dll. It helps, I found .cs file with connection string.
- Next, I used CFF Explorer to modify .cs inside .dll with HEX-editor and save it.
  How to build new .exe based on modified .dll?

Comment: "I used CFF Explorer to modify .cs inside .dll with HEX-editor" bad idea to modify the file using a hex editor, and any case the .cs is just for debugging, it's not the actual compiled code. Just use dotPeek to Export As Project, and then change what you want in Visual Studio and recompile.